# LDAP Integration Node.JS

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap, ldapjs

I'm developing a simple node app using ldapjs. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to make the connection with ldap.

Our IT department gave me the below credentials (some redacted for security).
[image]

My app.js file looks like the following. I just need to retrieve a user's data (given a username and password).

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');

var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: 'ldap://xx.xxx.xxx.xxxx/dc=xxxxx,dc=org'
});

var opts = {
  filter: '(objectclass=user)',
  scope: 'sub',
  attributes: ['objectGUID']
};

client.bind('xx@xxxx.org', 'xxxx', function (err) {
  console.log("Logging data...");
  client.search('dc=xxxx,dc=org', function (err, search) {
    search.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
      var user = entry.object;
      console.log(user.objectGUID);
    });
  });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any output to standard out? does `Logging data...` print?

Comment: Yes, it does. I'm not getting anything returned.

Comment: I would add more logging. Add console.logs as the first statements in the client.search callback and the search.on callback. That will help narrow down where exactly the issue occurs.

Comment: Ok. Honestly, it's my first time working with ldap. Does my code look right?

Comment: Here's the error I'm now getting: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
MacBook-Pro:node User$ node app.js
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Comment: I haven't used the specific LDAP library you are using, but at first glance the code looks reasonable. However, if you are getting a timeout error, that means that the LDAP module can't even connect to your ldap server. I would double check the ip address of the server you are connecting to, and do an nmap on it from your local machine to make sure the ports are open.